# Ignoring ' (apostrophe) from RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-matching, substring

I've a RegEx and would like to ignore any ' (apostrophe) within the string. RegEx discussion can be found within the discussion [String manipulation: How to replace a string with a specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464300/string-manipulation-how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-specific-pattern)

```
RegEx: \\(\\s*'(?<text>[^'']*)'\\s*,\\s*(?<pname>[\\w\\[\\]]+)\\s*\\)
```

Basically the provided RegEx doesn't work in a scenario where the {text} contains ' (apostrophe). Can you please have the RegEx to ignore any apostroph'e within the {text}?

```
For eg: 

substringof('B's',Name) should be replaced by Name.Contains("B's") 
substringof('B'',Name) should be replaced by Name.Contains("B'")
substringof('''',Name) should be replaced by Name.Contains("'")
```

Appreciate it!! Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the string you're searching for is something like: `( 'foo' , bar[]baz[] )` Note: You seem to be requiring apostrophe `'` at the end of the string.  If you want to "ignore" apostrophe, try something like: `([^'][']?)+` Which means, expected char set followed by optional apostrophe, then repeat 1 or more times.

Comment: Okay, will try & let you know

Comment: Thanks but sorry this didnt work

Comment: Odd, `'\([^'][']\?\)\+'` worked fine in vim.  By itself it will match `'B'` or `'B's'` equally well however.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why you want replace `''''` by `"'"` and not by `"''"` ?

Comment: @Casimir, I'm passing this replaced string to LINQ and it fails when you pass "''" instead of "'"

Comment: @EvolvingTechie: and can you pass something like `"aa''aa"`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be difficult to deal with the case `''''`. It's the reason why I choose to use *delegate* and an another *replace* to solve the issue.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var subjects = new string[] {"substringof('xxxx',Name)", "substringof('B's',Name)", "substringof('B'',Name)", "substringof('''',Name)"};

    Regex reg = new Regex(@"substringof\('(.+?)'\s*,\s*([\w\[\]]+)\)");
    foreach (string subject in subjects) {
        string result = reg.Replace(subject, delegate(Match m) { return m.Groups[2].Value + ".Contains(\"" + m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("''", "'") + "\")"; });
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. this worked perfectly for couple scenario's I tried. I've run few more tests.

Comment: Hi Casimir, I've couple scenario's that are not working in this case. 1. For eg: substringof('B'',Name) should be replaced by Name.Contains("B'") and 2. substringof('''',Name) should be replaced by Name.Contains("'")

Comment: `\k` should be `\\k` I think?  Also, this doesn't solve the (confusing) last example (converting `''` to `'`).  Seems the OP also wants to combine two side by side `'` into just one.  The part we solved earlier should probably just be `.*` now that I think about it.

Comment: yea, I figured \k shud be \\k & tested it out with that but still the updated pattern didnt work for scenario's 2 & 3